# Unable to install BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

```
abcdefg@HAL9000:~$ pip install beautifulsoup4
Downloading/unpacking beautifulsoup4
  Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz (131Kb): 131Kb downloaded
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 955, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1072, in unpack_url
    return unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, only_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 447, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 468, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/util.py", line 393, in untar_file
    os.makedirs(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/abcdefg/build/beautifulsoup4'

Storing complete log in /home/abcdefg/.pip/pip.log
```

Since I was getting permission denied, I tried running it with sudo,

```
abcdefg@HAL9000:~$ sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
Downloading/unpacking beautifulsoup4
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement beautifulsoup4
No distributions at all found for beautifulsoup4
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I know I can install it without pip as well, but I encountered this problem while installing requests as well, so I want to know the solution

Thanks!

Comment: try `sudo pip install bs4`

Comment: Your second attempt looks like a temporary failure, or a failure to use your configured proxy (if you have one). Make sure your root account has the same proxy environment variables set (if you have any), and retry.

Comment: Same problem with that package too. Btw, I'm behind a proxy. But if my proxy config is working without the sudo command, I don't see why it shouldn't work with the sudo command. Also, I was getting the same permission error while installing `requests`, but running pip install with sudo in that case worked without a problem.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, then *that is why* the sudo command failed. Check for the `http_proxy` env var in your root account setup.

Comment: `echo $http_proxy`, `sudo echo $http_proxy` and `sudo su` followed by `echo $http_proxy` all return the same proxy..!

Comment: Okay, solved it. I ran the command after exporting the proxy from inside `sudo su`. Apparently I have a command somewhere in some file which resets the proxy to some old configuration whenever I call `sudo`. Now off to find that file !